# Returning result from asynchronous function using callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, asynchronous-javascript

I have to write the body of a function getABC() which essentially has to take in responses from 3 different functions, getA()(synchronous),getB(callback)(callback driven),getC() (promise based).  Ultimately I have to return a promise aggregating each function's result, like [(result of getA),(result of getB),(result of getC)].

I am pasting the snippet of the code down below:

```
const [A,B,C] = ['A','B','C'];
function getA(){
 return A;
}
function getB(cb){
  setTimeout(()=>{
      cb(B);
  },10);
}
function getC()
{
   return Promise.resolve().then(()=>C)
}
function getABC()
{//Can only write the body of this function
var ARR=[];
const cb = async x =>{
const arr = [];
arr.push(getA());
arr.push(x);
arr.push(await getC());
console.log(arr); //Shows ['A','B','C'] required output
return arr;
}
let res = getB(cb);
console.log(res); //Shows undefined
return Promise.resolve().then(()=>ARR);
}
let arr = getABC().then((arr)=> console.log('Arr:',arr)); //Shows empty array ARR
```

`
I cannot edit any other part of the code excluding the getABC() function call. I cannot wrap my head around this problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```js
const[A,B,C]=["A","B","C"];function getA(){return A}function getB(t){setTimeout(()=>{t(B)},10)}function getC(){return Promise.resolve().then(()=>C)}

function getABC() {
  return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
    const a = getA()
    const c = await getC()
    getB((b) => resolve([a, b, c]))
  })
}

getABC().then(res => console.log(res))
```

The result from `getA` is returned immediately. `getC` returns a promise, so just `await` its result. Then call `getB` and resolve the promise in the callback.

Another option is to make `getABC` an `async` function as well. Note the difference in the way `getB` is called here.

```js
const[A,B,C]=["A","B","C"];
function getA(){return A}
function getB(t){setTimeout(()=>{t(B)},10)}
function getC(){return Promise.resolve().then(()=>C)}

async function getABC() {
  const a = getA()
  const b = await new Promise(resolve => getB(resolve))
  const c = await getC()
  return [a, b, c]
}

getABC().then(res => console.log(res))
```

The `getB` line can be further simplified using a technique called [eta reduction](https://sookocheff.com/post/fp/eta-conversion/). The same technique can be used for the `.then(res => console.log(res))` line.

```js
async function getABC() {
  const a = getA()
  const b = await new Promise(getB) // eta reduced
  const c = await getC()
  return [a, b, c]
}

getABC().then(console.log) // eta reduced
```

Comment: @SounavSaha I added some improvements that reduce complexity

Comment: @Spectric any time ^_^ feel free to edit to your satisfaction